# can i embed a single product into another page on wordpress so that it has the add to cart and variable options?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a single product with variables but I need it to show on a user profile page. I can easily put a sidebar in with best products or popular products but that means it needs another click to get to the product page. So I need the product displayed on a certain page with all the variables showing and add to cart also showing.